# How do I search my zsh aliases?

Tags: zsh, alias

Right now I do something like this:

```
cat ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh | grep alias | grep rebase
```

to search, say, git aliases that have rebase.  How do I search through all plugins that define aliases (or through all my defined aliases?) for keywords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man alias`:

```
If no operands are given, all alias definitions shall
be written to standard output.
```

You can use `alias`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that!

Answer (score 3):

As @ctx puts is the shell builtin `alias` command will list all the alias you have defined.

If you want to search for an alias you can use grep with it, For example if you want to list all the `git` alias:

```
alias | grep git
```